# Unable to convert AVAudioRecorder file to Data in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudiorecorder

let audiofilePath = recorderView.recording.url
  let fileLocation = audiofilePath.absoluteString

```
    var base64String: String = ""
    do {
        let fileData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: fileLocation, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
        base64String = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

It is throwing an error as belows :

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “1497293846.m4a” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/venkatkukunuru/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2C78C862-CB09-47F1-88EC-CBD854A248B3/data/Containers/Data/Application/B3A406FB-430D-4DBC-A5E2-7BCD7FBAF9F5/Documents/1497293846.m4a, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000455a50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: Well, like the error states, `fileLocation` does not point to a file that exists. Where is that variable set?

Comment: But I'm able to play the audio file which is at the same path

Comment: It's impossible to fix your issue based solely on the information that you provided in your question. Please provide the working code you use to play the file, and any sections of code that set `fileLocation`.